# Make a placeholder % sign pretend to stay

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is a peculiar question but, I have a input field, like this,

```
<div class="<?php if(form_error('interest')!= null){echo ' has-error';} ?>">
   <h4><?php echo lang("offer_of_intrest"); ?></h4>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('interest'); ?>" placeholder="1%" name="interest">
</div>
```

Where the placeholder says `1%`, but the input only accepts whole numbers ( 1 or 2 or 3 so on.. ) , What I want to do is somehow keep the percentage sign inside the place holder but make the user enter any number but keeping the percentage sign , but on submit of the button only the number should go , not with the percentage sign. Since in mysql it only accepts decimal places. Its like giving the user a fake percentage sign in placeholder so they dont get confused and actually enter 1( PERCENT) in the input field. , I hope this is understand able.

Comment: That's not the purpose of placeholder. In fact, you should use an input with attribute `type="number"` followed by any other HTML element repesenting the % sign. Your placeholder should describe how should be filled your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you seem to be using Bootstrap, I'd remove the `%` from the placeholder and use an `input-group` and an `input-group-addon`:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Percentage:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="1" name="interest">
          <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @A.Wolff: I just used the OP's `input`.

Comment: @A.Wolff i did not use type number since it had those arrows for choosing more numbers or less, so giving a -1 was unnecessary, i Just wanted to make it look better

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for ur answer, but I guess there is no other way, I really dint want to use addon

Answer (score 2):

You could split the string to splice out the '%' sign, then cast it to an int. ( Thanks to Bob Nocraz below )

```
$yourDecimal = rtrim($theVariable, '%');
$result = intval($yourDecimal);
```

Comment: why not just rtrim($theVariable, '%'); ?

Comment: True. Why not ? both solutions does the same thing :)

Comment: they only do the same thing if the input has a % in it.  if the user inputting the data didn't include a %, then this solution removes the last character

Answer (score 0):

Theres is no solution in Html in my knowledge but you can do this in Javascript.

```
$(input).keydown(function(){
   val = $(this).val()
   val = val.slice(val.length, 1);
   val += "%";
})
```

Maybe this would work